# My code worked; my goal is parse pdf into excel-multiple pages. I can only do one page as of right now

Tags: python

[image]

Hi trying to parse/convert pdf into excel to get specifics rows/columns, however i can only "convert", one page as of right now. Need help how to parse/convert multiples page of pdf into excel sheet.

Comment: [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: You can try pandas.ExcelWriter

Answer (score 0):

You're asking to process only page 1 with your options. So you can't have the other pages!
See the documentation extarct:
pages (str, int, list of int, optional)
An optional values specifying pages to extract from. It allows str, int, list of int.
Example: 1, '1-2,3', 'all' or [1,2]. Default is 1